# Add Control like appBar

Tags: panel, windows-phone, application-bar

I need your help please.

I need to add in my project, in the end of my page, a Control( that can be in stackpanel or not), something like application bar,

meaning, if I have a listbox, on all the page, and I'm adding a control in the end of the page, so now I need that the list box will be from the begining of the page, but just until the control and not continue under the control' on all the page.

I need to do it dynamically (in code).

Do someone have an idea how can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking of `Grid` row allocation, the way I see it. Something that was briefly covered in the [screen orientation quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207002%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). If you have three rows, have the middle one take all the space, while the top and the bottom take a fixed amount of space.